# Can ASP.NET Core 7 Web API class access configuration using dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I encountered an error when running the `dotnet watch` command in my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API. The error message I get:

> C:\code2\Target\Core\Application\Core.cs(13,50): error CS0103: The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context [C:\code2\Target\Target.csproj]

I have included the using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` statement, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. I am looking for a solution to this problem.

The only workaround that currently works for me is using the `builder.Configuration`  instance in my `program.cs` file, like this:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Target");
```

However, I want to avoid passing dependencies explicitly to my function or class, as shown here:

```
GetMenu(string connectionString ...)
```

Is there a way to inject or use dependency injection within the class to resolve this issue?

Here is a snippet of my code for reference:

```
// core/application/core.cs:
using Target.Core.Models;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Target.Core.Application;

public class Core
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Menu>> GetMenu()
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Target"]);
        connection.Open();
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        var result = await connection.QueryAsync<Menu>("get_menu", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        return result;
    }
}
```

My application is structured as follows:

```
// program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;

using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using System.Reflection;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Dapper;
using System.Data;

using Target.Models;
using Target.Core;
using Target.Core.Models;
using Target.Core.Application;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddCors();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Target");

app.MapGet("/menu", async (Core core) =>
{
    return await core.GetMenu();
});

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();
```

Is there a solution that allows me to use dependency injection within the Core class to access the configuration without explicitly passing it as a parameter?

Comment: AFAIK you can inject IConfiguration in your classes.

Comment: AS atomicicebreaker
  said , You can just inject `IConfiguration `  into your Core class, But I am confused that your project will not show error when you use Core as the parameter in `app.MapGet()`?

Comment: I try do add IConfiguration but I get null. @XinranShen yes the project is throw error about `Core`. so after a search on the web I found that I need to add `builder.Services.AddScoped<Core>()` and then I get the instance of `Core`. but all my services I need to do that? is there a way to dotnet to search those classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a demo to reproduce your project, Hope it can help you solve this issue.

```
public class Core
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        public Core(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetMenu()
        {
            var result = Configuration.GetConnectionString("default");
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
//register this service in container
 builder.Services.AddTransient<Core>();

//......

app.MapGet("/menu",async () =>
            {
                var core = app.Services.GetRequiredService<Core>();
                return await core.GetMenu();
            });
```

[image]

More details you can refer to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Thank you it's very helpul. Is there a way to "auto" detect all the classes instead do that for each service? ` builder.Services.AddTransient<....>();`

Comment: Do you mean you don't wanna register these services one by one? You can create a parent class and all these services inherit it, Then you just need to register this parent class in program.cs via autofac,